# enew is not allowed when used inside a function called by nnoremap <expr>

Tags: key-bindings, error

I have a function:

```
function myPlugin#myFunc()
  " ....
  enew
  termopen(['cmd', 'here'], termopen_opts)
endfunction
```

And in my `plugin/myPlugin.vim` I do:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>e myPlugin#myFunc()
```

But when I press `<leader>e` I get:

```
Error detected while processing function myPlugin#myFunc:
line   41:
E523: Not allowed here:     enew
```

But if I put in `plugin/myPlugin.vim`:

```
command! -nargs=+ MYCMD call myPlugin#myFunc()
nnoremap <leader>e :MYCMD<CR>
```

I don't get the error and `enew` does it's job. Any idea why?

Comment: Also, IIRC, you cannot have a function call as an ex command on its own (termopen...). You could echo, call, or return it, for just a few options, as those *are* ex commands

Comment: What you can do, is make your function return the commands that need to be executed, e.g. `return ":enew\<cr>:call termopen...."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limitations in things you can do in a function called from a `map-expression`.

From the docs:

```
Be very careful about side effects!  The expression is evaluated while
obtaining characters, you may very well make the command dysfunctional.
For this reason the following is blocked:
- Changing the buffer text |textlock|.
- Editing another buffer.
- The |:normal| command.
- Moving the cursor is allowed, but it is restored afterwards.
If you want the mapping to do any of these let the returned characters do
that.
```

And `:enew` wants to edit another (new) buffer.

See `:h map-expression`.

Try this:

```
nnoremap <leader>e :call myPlugin#myFunc()<cr>
```